# if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}S_{2k}$ exists, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=0$ , does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

${S_k} $ is the partial sum sequence of $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$,

Given $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}S_{2k}$  exists and  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=0$, can you prove that $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges?

My hunch is yes, but I get kind of stuck

to prove $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, we need to show that 
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}S_{2k+1} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}S_{2k}$$

we know $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}2a_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{2n+1} = 0$

I dont really know where to go from here, so any pointers would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try proving if $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\lim S_{2k}$ doesn't exist or $\lim a_n$ does not go to zero.

Comment: Use that $S_{2k+1}=S_{2k}+a_{2k+1}.$